# How to insert cell to collection view cell using swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, insert, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Am parsing api to collection view which works fine now i need to insert new cell which should perform action also

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage

 class EditPendingViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{


var favDict = NSMutableArray()





 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         JsonParsingFromURL()
       self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        FavCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1.0)
        FavCollectionView.hidden = false
        NoAdsview.hidden = true
        NoAdsview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 249/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1.0)

           JsonParsingFromURL()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 func JsonParsingFromURL(){
        self.view.makeToastActivity(.Center)
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
        {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, myapiKeyforsmart + "allad.php?customerid="+MyCustId+"", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                let FavMsg = (json["error_msg"]).stringValue
                self.view.hideToastActivity()
                if error != nil{
                    print("error occured = \(error)")
                }
               else if error == nil && FavMsg == "No favourite available"
                {
                   self.FavCollectionView.hidden = true
                   self.NoAdsview.hidden = false

                }
                else{
                       self.startParsing(data!)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            self.view.hideToastActivity()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "make sure your device is connected to the internet", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func startParsing(data :NSData)
    {
        let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
        for i in 0  ..< (dict.valueForKey("favourite Ads") as! NSArray).count
        {
            favDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("favourite Ads") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        }
        FavCollectionView.reloadData()
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favDict.count
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FavouriteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
        let adTitle:NSString = favDict[indexPath.item].valueForKey("adtitle") as! NSString
        let Price:NSString = favDict[indexPath.item].valueForKey("originalprice") as! NSString
        let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let numberFromField = (NSString(string: Price).doubleValue)
        let priceString = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)
        let address:NSString = favDict[indexPath.item].valueForKey("districtname") as! NSString
        let ImageString:NSString = favDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("images") as! NSString
        let parts = ImageString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        let firstImage = parts[0]
        cell.FavTitle.text = adTitle as String
        cell.FavPrice.text = priceString! as String
        cell.FavPrice.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor("#8000000", alpha: 0.5)
        cell.FavAddress.text = address as String
        cell.FavImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageApikey + (firstImage as String)))
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        if Price == "0"{
            cell.FavPrice.hidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
 }
```

This is my full code in view controller.I have searched other stack overflow answer nothing helps me can anyone help me to do this one

Comment: try reloading the collectionview on main thread after the almafire response in startParsing() method

Comment: @sathish kumar i have to insert new cell how to do that process

Comment: you are already adding the new data in favDict, that will do the job.. Just calling reload on collectionview will invoke its numberOfItemsInSection method, which will take the new favDict.count value.. Ideally !! keep breakpoint and check what is happening in your case

Comment: yes it works fine but i never done any process for adding new cell after loading api from the server

Comment: @satish Kumar where is your numberofrows in section method?

Comment: @TusharSharma have you understand my question??

Comment: @satish Kumar You want your API data to be shown on cells right?